# how to apply css to first and third saturday of datepicker() Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Apply CSS to first and third Saturday of every month eg. change the background color

[image]

Comment: Whats the relevant html that results from the use of the `datepicker()` plugin? What did you try? What happened, what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following JQuery code:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    beforeShowDay: specialDate
})
function specialDate(date) 
{
   if (date.getDay()==6 && (date.getDate()<=7 || (date.getDate()>=15 && date.getDate()<=21)))   
   {       
       return [true, 'special_day'];
   }
   return [true, ''];
}
```

Here `special_day` is my CSS Code,which is given below:

```
body .special_day 
{
   background-color: red;
}
```

I have attached my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XuuNC/32/).

You can check it. Good Luck!